# discord.ext.commands.bot Ignoring exception in command note

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, replit-database

I am trying to make a discord bot in python with a note command where te user can make a note. The note gets saved using the database from replit.

```
Imports, commands, prefix ect, ect (Prefix = !)

@bot.command()
async def note(ctx, *, note_add):
  author = ctx.author
  
  if note_add.lower() == "note" or "see":
    note_text = db[author]
    print(note_text)
  else:
    db[author] = note_add
```

Output when I tried !note (Some text)

```
2023-03-01 13:37:01 ERROR    discord.ext.commands.bot Ignoring exception in command note
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/DiscordBot/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 229, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 267, in note
    note_text = db[author]
  File "/home/runner/DiscordBot/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/replit/database/database.py", line 439, in __getitem__
    raw_val = self.get_raw(key)
  File "/home/runner/DiscordBot/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/replit/database/database.py", line 477, in get_raw
    r = self.sess.get(self.db_url + "/" + urllib.parse.quote(key))
  File "/nix/store/hd4cc9rh83j291r5539hkf6qd8lgiikb-python3-3.10.8/lib/python3.10/urllib/parse.py", line 870, in quote
    return quote_from_bytes(string, safe)
  File "/nix/store/hd4cc9rh83j291r5539hkf6qd8lgiikb-python3-3.10.8/lib/python3.10/urllib/parse.py", line 895, in quote_from_bytes
    raise TypeError("quote_from_bytes() expected bytes")
TypeError: quote_from_bytes() expected bytes

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/DiscordBot/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 1349, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "/home/runner/DiscordBot/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 1023, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)  # type: ignore
  File "/home/runner/DiscordBot/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 238, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: quote_from_bytes() expected bytes
```

Comment: Seems like author is not of type bytes or byte-like object. You might need to go for author.id or author.name, something like that. I don't know which properties are there in that class

Comment: I get the same error code when I try to make the author a id

Comment: how about str(author.id) ?

Comment: I have now a other error code. See [screenshot](https://gyazo.com/a01e81a6724197fed0ebff0535141f99))

Comment: Seems like your problem is solved. This is just saying that key doesn't exist in the database, rest is up to you to figure it out, good luck

Comment: I found it. Tnx for helping me :)

Comment: I forgot to write my comment as an answer. You could accept it as an answer and close the question.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like author is not of type bytes or byte-like object.
`note_text = db[author]`

You might need to go for author.id or author.name, something like that.